# What is fqn attribute in LightningComponentBundle?

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata

What is the `fqn` attribute in the `LightningComponentBundle` element? I can't find it documented anywhere. Is this the unique identifier by which Salesforce manages the element? Would that be the identifier used in the `members` element in `package.xml`? If I change it, does that change the "identity" of the component, so SF no longer thinks it's the same one?

See the example at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder, which contains the line

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
```

Comment: "fqn" usually means "fully qualified name", which, in SF, is usually the namespace + separator + local name.

Comment: Where did you come across this? I've not seen it anywhere so far. Can you provide an example of the meta XML for an LWC with this attribute in it? If so, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/313612/edit) your question to add it.

Comment: @PhilW it is used in LightningComponentBundle tag in Javascript meta xml file as seen in this page - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component

Comment: I suspect that is cruft from before LWCs were formalised. I certainly cannot find it in any specification, just in a few examples.